# how to resolve error "error compiling Cython file" error?

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to follow this [basic cython tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html). In my directory I've 

--> __ init__.py
-->hello.pyx
-->setup.py

Iniside hello.pyx-

```
print "Hello World"
```

Inside setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules = cythonize("hello.pyx"))
```

When I exceute `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`
I'm getting this error-

```
F:\bots\cython>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Compiling hello.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing hello.pyx
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
^
------------------------------------------------------------

cython:0:0: cython.hello is not available

Traceback (most recent call last):



File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
ext_modules = cythonize("hello.pyx")
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 778,in cythonize
      cythonize_one(*args[1:])
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 895, in cythonize_one
      raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
      Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: hello.pyx
```

It worked once and it generated hello.pyd as well but after this I installed few packages (tensorflow and others) using conda. But since then its not working and giving above error.

I've the [mingw installed using conda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mingw)

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `__init__.py` from that directory. For some reason, it confuses cython when trying compilation.

You can also consider using pyximport extension, like:
`import pyximport; pyximport.install()`, and then `import your_module`(as if it was a normal .py) if you just wish to import the .pyx files from normal python files. (In the latter case, `__init__.py` doesn't have to be removed.)